# How to customize custom post date format in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, date, custom-post-type

I've used custom field on my event called date. I want to display this date as:
MAY 23, 2017. But it's displaying as: 20170523. I've used this code.

```
<?php the_field( 'date' ); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using Advanced Custom Fields PRO? If yes, then you can try this:

```
<?php
$time = strtotime( get_field( 'date' ) );
$date = date( 'F d, Y', $time );

echo $date;
?>
```

More native way for Advanced Custom Fields PRO would be the following:

```
<?php
$date = get_field( 'date', false, false );
$date = new DateTime( $date );

echo $date->format('F d, Y');
?>
```

Comment: Thanks. The first one worked for me. Can I display month as NOV instead of november

Comment: Yes, sure, simply use M instead of F in format of the date.